# Databricks ARM Templatte Workspace Modifications

Tags: azure-databricks

Need to automate the different Workspace Settings in the Admin Console of Azure Databricks through  ARM Template or through a post deploy powershell code? For example in the image below I need to set Cluster visibility control as False or Table access control as True which should be set during deployment

Please provide a sample arm/powershell code for customizing workspace settings
[workspacesettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mM8i.png)

Answer (score 0):

These settings aren't controlled via ARM template as these are specific to a Databricks, while with ARM template you can only control Azure resources, but not their settings.

Some settings (not all) could be changed with [Workspace conf REST API](https://redocly.github.io/redoc/?url=https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/databricks/_static/api-refs/token-management-2.0-azure.json#operation/set-configuration), by sending PATCH request to `/api/2.0/workspace-conf` endpoint with JSON payload consisting of pairs setting name/value. (As alternative you can use [Databricks Terraform Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databrickslabs/databricks/latest/docs/resources/workspace_conf)). But most of these settings aren't documented, so it's better to reach solution architect or customer success engineer assigned to your organization.